# Escaping pre-processor directive in markdown for Doxygen

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I have the following line in my `mainpage.md`:

```
The forward-declaration headers must be `\#include`-d.
```

Doxygen 1.8.11 complains:

```
warning: explicit link request to 'include' could not be resolved
```

What is the workaround?

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant but something that does work: The forward-declaration headers must be  <code>\#include</code>-d.

Comment: @albert First, it works! Why do I need to escape `#` inside <code>?